# create list items with array values

Tags: php, html, arrays, jquery-mobile

How can I create with this arrays list items? Every array should create a new list item. At bottom I tried to realize it with print, but I dont know how I can set the values into the html elements. Or should I make a function and not with print?

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 61 [0] => 61 [autorid] => 13 [1] => 13 [date] => 2015-06-11 [2] => 2015-06-11 [longitude] => 13.6483 [3] => 13.6483 [latitude] => 53.8249 [4] => 53.8249 [title] => uiuo [5] => uiuo [text] => oujo [6] => oujo ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 62 [0] => 62 [autorid] => 15 [1] => 15 [date] => 2015-06-11 [2] => 2015-06-11 [longitude] => 13.6889 [3] => 13.6889 [latitude] => 53.8551 [4] => 53.8551 [title] => fghoir [5] => fghoir [text] => örlhkwrioiw [6] => örlhkwrioiw ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 63 [0] => 63 [autorid] => 16 [1] => 16 [date] => 2015-06-11 [2] => 2015-06-11 [longitude] => 13.6888 [3] => 13.6888 [latitude] => 53.8551 [4] => 53.8551 [title] => ghoghnohi [5] => ghoghnohi [text] => hnhj [6] => hnhj ) )

```
print('<li data-corners="false" id="<?php id; ?>" data-shadow="false" data-wrapperels="div" data-theme="b" ><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a class="ui-link-inherit"><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong><?php date; ?></strong></p>');
                    print('<p class="ui-li-heading"><?php title; ?><strong></strong></p>');
                    print('<p class="ui-li-desc">class="ui-li-heading"><?php text; ?></p>');
                    print('<p class="ui-li-desc"><?php autor; ?></p>');

                print('</a></li>');
```

Comment: you're already in PHP, so why the `<?php` and `?>`? Plus, variables don't get parsed in single quotes if you plan on fixing `<?php title; ?>` to `<?php $title; ?>`

Comment: then you have this `<?php autor; ?>` etc. - `id` `date` `title` - `autor` and `text` are being treated as constants. are they indeed pre-defined constants?

Comment: *"I'm blowing bubbles again, Sam"*. - Bloop bloop

Comment: *"Tiny ones Ralph"*. To paraphrase a song @Fred-ii-

Comment: *"In the wine....."* ♫ *"makes me feel happy..."* - @JayBlanchard - It does *Sam*, it really does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php). Something like:

```php
<ul>

<?php foreach ($nameOfYourArray as $key => $row): ?>

  <li>
    <p><?php echo $row['autorid']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row['date']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row['longitute']; ?></p>
    <!-- and more... -->
  </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will use `foreach`, something like this

```
foreach($your_array as $nested_array){
 echo "<li>" . $nested_array['id'] . " - " . $nested_array['date'] . "</li>"
}
```

and print will `print` the html tag and not render them, use `echo` instead.

is that what you wanted?